# How do I get the length of a Vec after it has been modified?

Tags: rust

I have a function which takes a Vec and pushes zero or more elements to it. The Vec and the reference passed to the function are both `mut`. When I try to get the length of the Vec upon return (to see how many elements were pushed), I get the dreaded "cannot borrow 'foo' as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable" error.

In general, I get why this error exists in general. I *don't* get why it's necessary here.

Surely there's a way to do this -- I can't be the first person who has tried something like this.

Here's a stripped-down version of what I'm trying to do, that replicates the error.

```
fn main() {
    let mut stack = vec!["one"];
    push(&mut stack, "two");
}

fn push<'a>(stack: &'a mut Vec<&'a str>, value: &'a str) {
    stack.push(value);
}

#[test]
fn test_len() {
    let mut stack = vec!["one"];
    push(&mut stack, "two");
    assert_eq!(stack.len(), 2);
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `stack` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:14:16
   |
13 |     push(&mut stack, "two");
   |          ---------- mutable borrow occurs here
14 |     assert_eq!(stack.len(), 2);
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                |
   |                immutable borrow occurs here
   |                mutable borrow later used here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't force the references lifetime and the lifetime of the mutable borrow to be the same.

```rust
fn push<'a>(stack: &mut Vec<&'a str>, value: &'a str) {
    stack.push(value);
}
```

Comment: I swear I wrote `&'a mut Vec` originally only because I got a warning/error when I didn't have it. I've removed it from the current code and you're right, it works as I'd expect.

Comment: @isaactfa The convention is to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer, yes?

Comment: [Not really](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255819/should-i-wait-before-accepting-an-answer) it's up to you.

Comment: @CraigS.Cottingham The SO help center only states "Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally." Do with that what you will.